# Programmatically increase max_allowable_packet in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a 28 MB sized SQL database. When I try to run a query through my C# application `max_allowable_packet` allowed not allowed pops up.But when I manually change MySQL my.ini file and increase the max_allowable_packet size to 512 it works fine.So my query is, I want to programmatically write code to increase the `max_allowable_packet` size. Is it possible through C#?

Comment: No these config values should be changed explicitly in mysql server not by any programming language accessing them.

Comment: You may be solving the wrong problem.  Since you didn't tell us anything about the error, we have no idea, but if you set the *client* max_allowed_packet setting correctly -- to match the server -- no server change might be needed.  There are independent settings on client and server sides, and a lot of bad advice on the Internet on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max_allowed_packet variable can be set globally by running a query
Try execute this query command

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet= your_value;
```

Comment: i tried it but when ever xampp restarts the max_allowable_packet value sets to default

Comment: then or you change the value  in configuration file or you set the value when you need (starting the application for example)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response!!

Comment: i have one small query!! can i programatically replace my.ini file because i want to update and circulate my.ini file to my clients. If i ask them to replace default ini file by the one i circulated it will be troublesome to my clients so i want to do it programatically. Is It Possible??

Comment: if you have the right permissione you can open the file search for the entry you need  assign the value and save .. if a entry in any file some languages have proper function for this  .. check for C# .. othewise  .. parse the file  .yourself ..

Comment: precisely what i am thinking to do is manually change mysql my.ini file max_allowed_packet value . Then i will attach updated my.ini file with the project and circulate it to my clients.when the application runs it will automtically replace default my.ini file of xampp installed in client machine by the one i sent!!

Comment: i act some time dumb as a sheep!!! sorry for the trouble.....sometime i couldn't solve such simple problems. My Bad....... solution of my problem just hit me!!!!! you can do file.Replace or file.Copy!!!!!!!!!